# Magento 2 Grid Component: Persistent Pagination possible?

Tags: magento2

When I browse through any backend grid in Magento 2, for example the product list for Magento_Catalog, the pagination is not persistent.

What I mean:

- Go to the product list and make sure more than one page exists (for example 60 products are available and only 20 are shown => 3 pages total)
- go to page two for example
- open any product
- wait for the edit view to open and then go "back" using the provided links

When I do this, I always come back to page 1. This is a real problem for my client, because there are a lot of products he has to go through from time to time.

What I would expect: save the current page somewhere. When you come back to the grid, don't fall back to page 1.

I have two questions:

- Is the table ui_bookmark supposed to provide this persistance? There is a column "current", which could possibly be related to the "current" setting of the Grid Component.
- If this is not supported right away, any hint where I could start to look into for an implementation? As of yet, I don't fully understand the complete structure of the grid as a whole.

Btw: This problem is also true for custom grids I've created.